# Lager loglevels per application

Tags: erlang, lager

How can I set different loglevels per application/library in Lager?

For example, I would like to see debug messages on the console, but only for my application, not for any libraries I use (eg. amqp_client).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can't be (easily) done with `lager:debug`, etc. However, with lager 3.x, you can now have multiple [sinks](https://github.com/basho/lager#user-content-sinks), which means that you could define a sink named `myapp`, and use `myapp:debug`, etc.. Then you can configure the logging levels, filters and destinations independently for each sink.